# Telerik radgridview CellFormatting is not stable

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I have a radgridview with many columns (Horizontal Scroll Bar has been activated).
I have a CommandColumn in my grid & i want to format it like this :

```
private void rad_grd_Requests_CellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CellElement.ColumnInfo is GridViewCommandColumn)
        {
            RadButtonElement button = (RadButtonElement)e.CellElement.Children[0];
            if (e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells["Admin_Action"].Value.ToString() == "Hold")
            {
                button.Text = "Done";
            }
            else
            {
                button.Text = "Done";
                button.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Hidden;
            }
        }
    }
```

When program starts every thing is ok.
But when i use horizontal scroll bar of grid some times all buttons in CommandColumn be invisible.(Multiple run of CellFormatting())
Why CellFormatting() is not stable & how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer :

```
   RadButtonElement button = (RadButtonElement)e.CellElement.Children[0];
    if (e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells["Admin_Action"].Value.ToString() == "Hold")
    {
        button.Text = "Done";
        button.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        button.Text = "Done";
        button.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Add `button.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Visible;` to you codes.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the UI virtualization in RadGridView, cell elements are created only for currently visible cells and are being reused during operations like scrolling, filtering, grouping and so on. In order to prevent applying the formatting to other columns' cell elements (because of the cell reuse), all customization should be reset for the rest of the cell elements.

Please refer to the following help article demonstrating how to properly customize the cells and reset the style: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/cells/formatting-cells

I hope this information helps.